# Finding minimum number of points which covers entire set of intervals?

Tags: algorithm, intervals

Given a set of intervals  `[x,y] where 0 <= x,y  <= 2000` how to find minimum number of points which can cover(i.e. Every interval should contain at least one point in resultant set of points) all intervals?

example:

```
Given Set of intervals:
    [2,5]
    [3,7]
    [7,10]
```

then answer should be  2 (minimum number of points required to cover all intervals) as points `x=3,x=7` is one solution.

Comment: that's np-complete problem but you might want to use some greedy heuristics

Comment: I tried to solve this using making ArrayLists for each of points between 0 and 2000 using deduction method. But i got stuck in between where i need to find minimal point set which cover 1 to n numbers

Comment: The answer is 2, not 3. You can pick 5 and 10.

Comment: I second user2040251. There are 3 solutions to the example 3,10; 4,10; 5,10.

Comment: oh actually i made a wrong analogy with set cover problem, ) that's not np-complete, it has optimal greedy solution, see the answer below

Comment: looks simmilar to http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/ONEKING

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a greedy algorithm:

1. Sort all intervals by their end points(in increasing order).
2. Iterate over a sorted array of intervals. When an interval is over, there are two options:

   1. It is already covered by some point. Nothing should be done in this case.
   2. It is not covered yet. Then the end point of this interval should be inserted into to the resulting set.

The resulting set generated by this algorithm is optimal.

Comment: how do you prove it's optimum solution? It doesn't necessarily is optimum.

Comment: This comment to a similar question tries to answer why this is optimal:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4962774/784669