# connected components in undirected graphs in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, connected-components

I wanted to count the number of groups in an undirected graphs in c++.I was trying using bfs but was unsuccessful.I have been given a range of numbers [L,R] (or think of these ranges as number of vertices) and i have to find the number of groups.How do i do this?

Like if i have (Input):

```
1 3
2 5
6 9
```

Output:

```
2
```

As there are 2 groups.

My code:

```
bool visited[MAX];
vector<int> v[MAX];
int solve(int x)
{
  queue<int> q;int ans=0;
  q.push(x);
  if(v[x].empty())
  {
      ans++;
  }
  while(!q.empty())
  {
      int curr = q.front();
      visited[curr] = true;
      q.pop();
      for(int i = 0; i < v[curr].size(); i ++)
        {
            if(!visited[v[curr][i]])
            {
                q.push(v[curr][i]);
                visited[v[curr][i]] = true;
            }
        }
        if(v[curr].empty()) ans++;
  }
  return ans;
}
int main()
{
    int t;scanf("%d",&t);

    while(t--)
    {
        int l,r,n,ans=0,min_,max_=0;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
            visited[i] = false;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&l);scanf("%d",&r);
            for(int i=l;i<r;i++)
            {
                v[i].push_back(i+1);
                 min_ = min(min_,i);
                max_ = max(max_,i+1);
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n",solve(min_));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "But it was unsuccessful". What did go wrong? Did your program crash? Did it produce incorrect output?

Comment: @user111 It seems like you have a different idea on how to define graphs. Typically they are defined by a bunch of `std::pair<int>`s with each element of the pair representing a node. Your input is "1->3, 2->5, 6->9" and you say that will make "2" graphs? To be clear that should make **3 graphs**, you agree with that, right?

Comment: @JonathanMee It will make graphs : 1->2->3->4->5  and 6->7->8->9 . So, 2 graphs.

Comment: @IloveCoding I got Runtime Error(SIGSEGV). I just need to know how do i count groups in an undirected graph.

Comment: @user111 How large can n, L and R be?

Comment: 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5, 0 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ 2000

Comment: You mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745166/algorithms-used-to-find-the-overlaps-sets)? And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753830/finding-minimum-number-of-points-which-covers-entire-set-of-intervals)? And this http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/ONEKING?

Comment: @beaker They look different to me. This one is about finding the number of connected components, the last 2 links are about something like vertex cover.

Comment: @beaker The first is about finding the largest set of segments. The second two are about finding the minimum number of points which connect to all segments. This question is related but is about finding the number of disconnected segment sets. (And notably not at all about graphing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at how many edges are created in the worst case. It is `N * (MAX_R - MIN_L)`, which is `10^5 * 2000` under given constraints. You program runs out of memory and gets runtime error. A more efficient algorithm is required. Here is a simple solution that uses only `O(MAX_R)` memory and 
`O(N + MAX_R)` time.

```
vector<int> start(MAX_R + 1);
vector<int> end(MAX_R + 1);
int n;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int low;
    int high;
    cin >> low >> high;
    start[low]++;
    end[high]++;
}
int res = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int pos = 0; pos <= MAX_R; pos++) {
    if (sum == 0 && start[pos] > 0)
        res++;
    sum += start[pos] - end[pos];
}
cout << res << endl;
```

There is no need for bfs or any other graph algorithms in this problem.

You could fix your original solution by avoiding multiple edges in the graph(there is no need to create an edge from `i` to `i + 1` if it already exists, but I am not sure if your original solution is correct).

Comment: So,here MAX_R is 2000. ? @ILoveCoding

Comment: I am getting 1 as the output for the input i provided above,but it should be 2 . @ILoveCoding

Comment: @usr111 I edited my answer a couple of minutes ago. There was a bug, now it works properly.

Comment: I think it still contains some bugs ..@ILoveCoding

Comment: @user111 Why do think so? Do you have a test case which it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should start by changing to `vector<pair<int,int>> v;`. Then to populate `v` you should use:

```
scanf("%d", &l);scanf("%d", &r);
v.push_back(make_pair(l, r);
```

Then your function should become something like:

```
int solve(){
    vector<pair<int, int>> results;

    for(auto& vIndex : v){
        auto resultIndex = find_if(results.begin(), results.end(), [vIndex](const pair<int, int>& i){return vIndex.first >= i.first && vIndex.first <= i.second || vIndex.second >= i.first && vIndex.second <= i.second;});

        if(resultIndex == results.end()){
            results.push_back(vIndex);
        }else{
            resultIndex->first = min(vIndex.first, resultIndex->first);
            resultIndex->second = max(vIndex.second, resultIndex->second);
        }
    }
    return results.size();
}
```

You can see this in action here: http://ideone.com/MDQBOr Just hard code your desired inputs into `v`.

Comment: @user111 It's worth pointing out that what you are constructing is not a graph but an [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). My approach is brute force, if you needed to solve this quickly, using the tree described in the link would be a better approach.