# Minimum number of disconnections

Tags: java, algorithm, math, data-structures, heap

There are `N` cities connected by `N-1` roads.
Each adjacent pair of cities is connected by bidirectional roads i.e.

- `i-th` city is connected to `i+1-th` city for all `1 <= i <= N-1`, given as below:

`1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4...............(N-1) --- N`

We got `M` queries of type `(c1, c2)` to **disconnect** the pair of cities c1 and c2.
For that we decided to `block` some roads to meet all these `M` queries.

> **Now, we have to determine the minimum number of roads that needs to be
> blocked such that all queries will be served**.

**Example :**

```
inputs:
 -  N = 5 // number of cities
 -  M = 2 // number of query requests
 -  C = [[1,4], [2,5]] // queries

output: 1

Approach :
 1. Block the road connecting the cities C2 and C3 and all queries will be served.
 2. Thus, the minimum roads needs to be blocked is 1.
```

**Constraints :**

```
 - 1 <= T <= 2 * 10^5  // numner of test cases
 - 2 <= N <= 2 * 10^5  // number of cities
 - 0 <= M <= 2 * 10^5  // number of queries
 - 1 <= C(i,j) <=  N  

It is guaranteed that the sum of N over T test cases doesn't exceed 10^6.
It is also guaranteed that the sum of M over T test cases doesn't exceed 10^6.
```

**My Approach** :

> Solved this problem using **Min-Heap**, but not sure if it will work
> on all the **edges(corner) test cases** and has the **optimal
> time/space** complexities.

```
public int solve(int N, int M, Integer[][] c) {
    int minCuts = 0;
    if(M == 0) return 0;
    // sorting based on the start city in increasing order.
    Arrays.sort(c, (Integer[] a, Integer[] b) -> {
        return a[0] - b[0];
    });

    PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
    // as soon as I finds any end city in my minHeap which is less than equal to my current start city, I increment mincuts and remove all elements from the minHeap. 
    for(int i = 0; i < M ; i++) {
        int start = c[i][0];
        int end = c[i][1];

        if(!minHeap.isEmpty() && minHeap.peek() <= start) {
            minCuts += 1;
            while(!minHeap.isEmpty()) {
                minHeap.poll();
            }
        }
        minHeap.add(end);
    }

    return minCuts + 1;
}
```

Is there any any edge test-case for which this **approach** will fail?

Comment: *"Could you find any test-case for which this approach will fail?"*: looks like a question that is off topic here.

Comment: Of the questions you have asked before, 5 have answers, and yet you only marked one answer as accepted. I see some good answers there... Any reason why you don't mark satisfying answers as accepted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962015/given-a-set-of-intervals-find-the-minimum-number-of-points-that-need-to-be-plac

Comment: @trincot, I have marked the accepted answer and upvoted pretty much every answer in almost all my questions, the questions that I have not marked as accepted has either a very long explanation by the author thus it's taking time to understand it  completely OR they were just been posted 2-3 days back, will try to mark them accepted once I verify it ASAP.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, I read your approach. Sort by end time and then make current end point as output if last output end point less than that.
I guess the minHeap solution I posted will do the same thing, maybe it's not as time efficient as your's solution becoz I am sorting first and then using min-heap insertion/deletions.

Comment: @MattTimmermans. do you see case anywhere where my approach will fail !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each query, there is an (inclusive) interval of acceptable cut points, so the task is to find the minimum number of cut points that intersect all intervals.

The usual algorithm for this problem, which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962015/given-a-set-of-intervals-find-the-minimum-number-of-points-that-need-to-be-plac), is an optimized implementation of this simple procedure:

1. Select the smallest interval end as a cut point
2. Remove all the intervals that it intersects
3. Repeat until there are no more intervals.

It's easy to prove that that it's always optimal to select the smallest interval end:

- The smallest cut point must be <= the smallest interval end, because otherwise that interval won't get cut.
- If an interval intersects *any* point <= the smallest interval end, then it must also intersect the smallest interval end.
- The smallest interval end is therefore an optimal choice for the smallest cut point.

It takes a little more work, but you can prove that your algorithm is also an implementation of this procedure.

First, we can show that the smallest interval end is always the first one popped off the heap, because nothing is popped until we find a starting point greater than a known endpoint.

Then we can show that the endpoints removed from the heap correspond to exactly the intervals that are cut by that first endpoint.  All of their start points must be <= that first endpoint, because otherwise we would have removed them earlier.  Note that you didn't adjust your queries into inclusive intervals, so your test says `peek() <= start`.  If they were adjusted to be inclusive, it would say `peek() < start`.

Finally, we can trivially show that there are always unpopped intervals left on the heap, so you need that `+1` at the end.

So your algorithm makes the same optimal selection of cut points.  It's more complicated than the other one, though, and harder to verify, so I wouldn't use it.